# How to plot subplots horizontally and vertically aligned with respect to each other in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have 3 subplots in matplotlib (2 rows and 3 columns).
I intend to have the first subplot in the 1st row covering the all 3 columns;

second subplot in the 2nd row left most aligned

third subplot in the 2nd row right most aligned.

Both second and third subplots horizontally aligned to the top with respect to each other.

However with the code below, I could not horizontally align them.

I also used gridspec.GridSpec with some width_ratios.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib import gridspec

def plot_figure():
    xticklabels_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] * 6
    rows=['row1']

    plot1 = plt.figure(figsize=(5 + 1.5 * len(xticklabels_list), 5 + 1.5 * len(rows)))
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[1, 1, 1], height_ratios=[1, 1])
    top_axis = plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
    bottom_left_axis = plt.subplot(gs[-1, 0])
    bottom_right_axis = plt.subplot(gs[-1, -1])
    plot_at_bottom_left_axis(bottom_left_axis)

    top_axis.set_xlim([0, 36])
    top_axis.set_xticklabels([])

    top_axis.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=0, labelsize=35)
    top_axis.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 36, 1))
    top_axis.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 36, 1) + 0.5, minor=True)
    top_axis.set_xticklabels(xticklabels_list, minor=True)

    top_axis.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
    top_axis.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

    plt.tick_params(
        axis='x',  # changes apply to the x-axis
        which='major',  # both major and minor ticks are affected
        bottom=False,  # ticks along the bottom edge are off
        top=False)  # labels along the bottom edge are off

    # CODE GOES HERE TO CENTER Y-AXIS LABELS...
    top_axis.set_ylim([0, len(rows)])
    top_axis.set_yticklabels([])

    top_axis.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=0, labelsize=40)

    top_axis.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(rows), 1))
    top_axis.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(rows), 1) + 0.5, minor=True)
    top_axis.set_yticklabels(rows, minor=True)  # fontsize

    plt.tick_params(
        axis='y',  # changes apply to the x-axis
        which='major',  # both major and minor ticks are affected
        left=False)  # labels along the bottom edge are off

    # Gridlines based on major ticks
    top_axis.grid(which='major', color='black', zorder=3)

    # Put the legend
    legend_elements = [ Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='white', label='legend1', markerfacecolor='red',markersize=40),
                        Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='white', label='legend2', markerfacecolor='green',markersize=40)]

    bottom_right_axis.set_axis_off()
    bottom_right_axis.legend(handles=legend_elements, ncol=len(legend_elements), bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc='upper right',fontsize=40)

    figFile = os.path.join('/Users/burcakotlu/Desktop', 'test.png')
    plot1.savefig(figFile, dpi=100, bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.cla()
    plt.close(plot1)

def plot_at_bottom_left_axis(ax):
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([0, 1, box.width * 1, box.height * 1], which='active')

    diameter_labels = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
    diameter_ticklabels = ['label1', '', '', '', 'label2', '', '', '', '', 'label3']

    row_labels = ['circle']
    ax.grid(which="major", color="w", linestyle='-', linewidth=3)

    plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), color='white')
    ax.set_aspect(1.0)
    ax.set_facecolor('lightcyan')

    # CODE GOES HERE TO CENTER X-AXIS LABELS...
    ax.set_xlim([0, len(diameter_labels)])
    ax.set_xticklabels([])

    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='both', length=0, labelsize=30)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(diameter_labels), 1))
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(diameter_labels), 1) + 0.5, minor=True)
    ax.set_xticklabels(diameter_ticklabels, minor=True)

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

    plt.tick_params(
        axis='x',  # changes apply to the x-axis
        which='both',  # both major and minor ticks are affected
        bottom=False,  # ticks along the bottom edge are off
        top=False)  # labels along the bottom edge are off

    ax.set_xlabel('labels to be shown', fontsize=40, labelpad=10)

    ax.set_ylim([0, len(row_labels)])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

    ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='minor', length=0, labelsize=12)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(row_labels), 1))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, len(row_labels), 1) + 0.5, minor=True)

    plt.tick_params(
        axis='y',  # changes apply to the x-axis
        which='major',  # both major and minor ticks are affected
        left=False)  # labels along the bottom edge are off

plot_figure()
```

Here is the resulting figure for the code above.

[image]

Comment: What I think you want to do is pretty simple, but it would really help if you minimized your code first.  You may even figure out the path forward yourself!

Comment: @JodyKlymak I have simplified the code. I hope it helps. I lowered the height of the figure. But still the bottom left axis and bottom right axis do not vertically align w.r.t. each other. I wish I have a better control over them.

Comment: What do you mean they “do not vertically align with each other”?  You are hiding the bottom right axes but I assure you it is vertically aligned with the bottom left axes

Comment: Is there a way to see bottom left and bottom right boxes axes?

Comment: Don’t call set_axis_off?